# Symfony Registration Form not Saving to Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've followed the guidance https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html to create a simple user creation page and save the form values to doctrine. The page loads great however when I fill out and submit the form to create a new user, the page reloads with the email pre-filled and a validation error of data.password must not be null. 
It doesn't look like its saved the entity to the database.

I can't figure out what is stopping it from saving. Just to test things I did create a dummy user using the UserFixtures and this saved successfully.

I think its related to the password encoding but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. Below is my setup - anyone have any ideas why the form is not saving to the database?

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }



    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

Registration Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
     */
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler, LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );


            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
                $user,
                $request,
                $authenticator,
                'main' // firewall name in security.yaml
            );
        }

        return $this->render('security/register.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return User[] Returns an array of User objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?User
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
}
```

Security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto


    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout: 
                path: app_logout
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            remember_me:
                    secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                    lifetime: 86400
                    path: /
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Form

```
{% extends 'base.nomenu.twig' %}

{% block title %}Create Account{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container login">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h1>Please complete the form to create an account</h1>

            {{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
            {{ form_row(registrationForm.email) }}
            {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword) }}

            <button class="btn">Register</button>
        {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit - RegistrationFormType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Insert a dump($form->getData());die; as your first statement inside the IF after submiting the form, and check if plainPassword is not empty. It probably is, as I didnt saw the plainPassword attribute in your entity. 
Could you edit your post with your Form Type class?

Comment: @JoaoVictorSouza Yes its showing a blank entry for plainPassword - I've included the form type class

Comment: Is it showing a blank entry or no entry at all? Usually with unmapped inputs you can't access them with $form->get('inputName)->getData(). But you can use the Request object. Dump $request->request->get('RegistrationFormType')['plainPassword'] and see if it contains your input value

Comment: @JoaoVictorSouza shows null

Comment: How about `$form['plainPassword']->getData()` ?

Comment: @msg that produces the password that I enter into the password box

Comment: So, now the password encoding works and the error is gone?

Comment: @msg thats crazy - i didn't change anything but now its working?! Yes its now created the user and stored the value - spent hours racking my brain on this!